# gui/libgui.a(x.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XSetForeground' when compiling Bosh

Tags: compiling

I need to compile bochs from source, I've already run this command:

```
./configure --with-x11 --with-wx --enable-ne2000 --enable-gdb-stub
 --enable-disasm --enable-e1000 --enable-usb --enable-pci
```

now it's time to run make.. after a while I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: gui/libgui.a(x.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XSetForeground'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any clue?

Comment: I don't think that bochs source have this kind of bug. By the way the source can be downloaded from bochs homepage

Comment: Installing xorg-dev fixed the problem! Thanks!! :)

Comment: Next time you may also use auto-apt http://askubuntu.com/q/376217/169736

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use `--with-x11` you need the `xorg-dev` package installed.

```
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

This will take care of all the possible dependencies that Bosch will need.

Comment: Mate I've another error with bochs dependencies: http://askubuntu.com/questions/376204/bochs-compiling-error-again