# 'undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' while compiling bochs

Tags: compiling, gcc

I'm trying to compile bochs with this command:

```
./configure --with-x11 --with-wx --enable-ne2000 --enable-iodebug --enable-disasm --enable-debugger --enable-e1000 --enable-usb --enable-pci
```

it works, but then when I run make I got:

```
usr/bin/ld: gui/libgui.a(gtk_enh_dbg_osdep.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Any Help ? :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `-lpthread` to the Makefile under LIBS

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when configuring a Bochs build with `--enable-debugger`, and seems to be a bug in Bochs's automatic build configuration wherein it incorrectly omits `-pthread` from the linker flags on Linux platforms.

There is no need to edit the `Makefile` as suggested in the previous answer. Rather, the workaround is to specify `LDFLAGS='-pthread'` when configuring the build; for example:

```
./configure --enable-debugger LDFLAGS='-pthread'
```

I've filed [bug report #1364](https://sourceforge.net/p/bochs/bugs/1364/) with the Bochs project. Please chime in over there to make sure the developers note and fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
tar vxzf bochs-2.4.5.tar.gz
cd bochs-2.4.5
sudo ./configure --enable-debugger --enable-disasm LDFLAGS='-pthread'
make
sudo make install
```