# Error when compiling bochs

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to compile bochs. Here is my configure command:

```
./configure --enable-fpu --enable-3dnow --enable-x86-64 --enable-a20-pin --enable-cdrom --enable-debugger --enable-debugger-gui --enable-disasm
```

Then I enter the "make" command and it compiles for some time. But then comes an error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: gui/libgui.a(gtk_enh_dbg_osdep.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bochs] Error 1
```

Can anybody help me with this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is a bug in the source of bochs that you are using, it is not explicitly linking to libpthread.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/376204/bochs-compiling-error-again