# How to install build dependencies for source not available in Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: compiling, install-from-source

I keep myself busy compiling (`make`ing) several packages and some of them are not in the repositories (so `apt-get build-dep` doesn't help), the complete documentation about build dependencies is missing or lacking, or I just don't know what library is lacking. Is there a way that I can just build something and if some header is missing it gets installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `auto-apt`. This tool gets a list of all the files contained in the repositories, along with the packages and installs the dependencies that your programs look for. It's syntax is a mixture of what apt-file offers with the plus that you don't have to figure out the error that `make` or `configure` shows you, and you don't need to do a search manually. It installation and use is easy.

#### Prerequisites

You must install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install auto-apt
```

and then update the package list (this is recommended at least before you start building something):

```
sudo auto-apt update
```

#### Usage

There are two ways you can use it:

```
auto-apt run command
```

it will run the command, if it finds some file that doesn't exist in your box it will ask you to put your sudo password and install it.

```
sudo auto-apt run
```

This will drop you in a non-root shell while the auto-apt main program will have root privileges. Any file operation will be performed by your user, so you don't have to fear about using root account.

#### Other interesting stuff

auto-apt includes a `debuild` command that will list you all building dependencies without actually building anything. This is a helper for first time maintainers that wants to compile/maintain their own version of packages not available in the Ubuntu/Debian ecosystem.

Comment: Sadly, auto-apt is quite dead nowadays. If anyone coming here has a newer solution, that would be greatly appreciated. :/