# How to install Qt

Tags: package-management, qt, make, synaptic, qmake

I am trying to build the Linux kernel using

```
make xconfig
```

but I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGAIW.png):

```
$ make xconfig
  CHECK qt
* Unable to find the QT4 tool qmake. Trying to use QT3
*
* Unable to find any QT installation. Please make sure that
* the QT4 or QT3 development package ts correctly installed and
* either qmake can be found or install pkg-config or set
* the QTDIR environment variable to the correct location.
*
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `scripts/kconfig/.tmp_qtcheck', needed by `scripts/kconfig/qconf.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [xconfig] Error 2
```

So I used Synaptic package tool to install Qt, now there are some of Qt things installed already and some are not. It specifically said to have `qmake`, I installed from Synaptic, again the same error as above.

[image: qt in synaptic manager]

How can I know which packages `xconfig` needs?

Comment: Give textual output from terminal instead of a picture

Comment: Is picture not visible?

Comment: Textual output is more useful for locating a question. Visibility is not the only problem here. And Edit your language in the question

Comment: What is what ???? Hahaha. Welcome to the process of learning, any ways why not try getting it from _[Qt](https://www.qt.io/download/)_ instead.

Comment: @Anwar language edited.

Comment: Building a Linux kernel requires gathering enough knowledge about the process which you cannot earn just by spending 2-3 hours. Research about the process, have patience and eventually You'll build it. Everyone who built it, went through it.

Comment: I have built linux kernel many times, just never used xconfig. I can make it work, but when the error says it needs qmake, I will then install qmake. It should work but it didn't. Now again it will throw me into an abyss of not knowing. I say kill those who says they made ubuntu great for this small problem

Comment: Please stop rollbacking.

Comment: @pointeraccurate you could've researched before you made this question; thus not wasting your 30 mins.

Comment: No I won't research everytime for every step I do in every 3 seconds.

Comment: Would you please post the solution you found in the answer section below instead of as edit to your question? Thank you.

Comment: There is no clarity given as what was not their in my PC. It just works so still I learned nothing.

Comment: @pointeraccurate well there is a lot of knowledge on the web; why not just search and it'll pop up

Comment: Wow you are lucky! The error you got was `unable to find the QT4 tool qmake` and all you needed was `qt4-qmake` (almost exactly named like the error said) and `libqt4-dev` (you always need a `lib*-dev` that sounds something like the package `make` complains about, right?) My answer to the question "how do I know which package xconfig needed" would be "put it in Google and hope the answer is on [SO], or try `apt search and trial & error." Compiling stuff is just annoying like that!

Comment: This helps if you're building something in repositories [How do I find the build dependencies of a package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21379/how-do-i-find-the-build-dependencies-of-a-package) there's also http://askubuntu.com/questions/376217/how-to-install-build-dependencies-for-source-not-available-in-ubuntu-repositorie

Comment: Even typical builder from source knows that you can't exactly guess the dev package required, it's always trial and error process. This is nothing new in Linux world and isn't an Ubuntu symptom at all! You said you compiled kernel many times, that is surprising from you. You should have learnt this in very beginning I think. Anyway, Check the answers of the links @Zanna posted.

Comment: So there is nothing solid at base level of learning kernel, how do you guys became so confident?

Comment: Qt is not a requirement to build the Linux kernel. You can use [`make menuconfig`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menuconfig) (using ncurses) or [`make oldconfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178526/what-does-make-oldconfig-do-exactly-in-the-linux-kernel-makefile) (no additional requirements).

Answer (score 3):

With `qmake` we need `libqt4-dev` too, that wasn't suggested in the error and we are on our own to figure it out, out of all qt packages what we need.

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev
```

or search `qt4-qmake` and `libqt4-dev` in Synaptic package manager and install respectively.

So I installed `qt4-qmake` but I also needed to install `libqt4-dev`, that I didn't.

P.S.
As suggested in one comment I did this

```
apt-rdepends --build-depends --follow=DEPENDS qt4-qmake
apt-rdepends --build-depends --follow=DEPENDS libqt4-dev
```

the list for qt4-qmake does not show that it needs libqt4-dev neither libqt4-dev shows it needs qt4-qmake.

Comment: it is the application you're building that has those dependencies - they are not dependencies of each other

Comment: what is the application here, xconfig?

Comment: I think you were building a kernel. so I guess I mean the kernel?